# Soundcard with 1/4" stereo input?

Tags: sound-card

Anyone ever seen a sound card with at least 1 stereo 1/4" audio jack?

Comment: Buy an adapter ([LINK](http://www.fullcompass.com/product/353162.html))? This is how I record from my guitar into my MacBook. Or is there a particular advantage to what you're looking for besides not needing an additional part?

Comment: The only real reason is so I can connect a pair of high end studio monitor headphones directly to the computer. I was wanting to eventually get my hands on some turntables and play around with mixing. But I would think the turntables would probably be XLR.

Comment: gotcha, though I would bet it might have multiple input/outputs, at least if they're anything like sound boards. I've worked with 10+ channel soundboards and they frequently feature xlr, rca, and 1/4". Regardless of what you do, you're probably going to be fine with the number of adapters out there from x to y. Good luck with your search!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most high grade gear has those and XLR jacks. I'm fairly partial to the maudio line (i own a fastrack 2, and a mbox) - even the extremely basic fastrack has one 1/4 inch in, 1 1/4 inch out and a xlr jack.

From what i heard about turntables, they come with phono outs - which are fairly similar to RCA except for line levels - so you may want to check up on what they use.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen *dozens* of computer audio interfaces with at least one 1/4" stereo jack output. Many of those listed [here](http://www.dv247.com/search/3152/0/ProductPrice/Ascending/-/1/), for instance.